# How to Integrate a Differential equation with all constant?

Tags: integration

> $$\int \frac12m\left(\frac{du}{dt}\right)^2\,dt$$

Actually I am not familiar with partial differential equation concept . As i have to integrate here with respect to $dt$ is there any way to integrate? To me it seems like all are constant because the function here it has nothing respect to t . How will i integrate this with simple Integration concept because i have just started the basic .

Thanks

Comment: Hi Hoppo! Welcome to Math.Stack exchange. I believe you forgot to include the equation you're having trouble with?

Comment: What function are you trying to integrate? If all of the terms are constant with respect to $t$ then you just multiply the expression that you have by $t$.

Comment: ops sorry  my bad !

Comment: Thanks i have edited my post

Comment: @AngelPeñaflor i didnt understand your point .

Comment: If $u$ is constant, then $\frac{du}{dt} =0$ and you’re done and if not, then you have to know $u$ as a function of $t$ to make any progress.

Comment: @Tavish i didnt understand the last point " you have to know u as a function  of t to make any progress.

Comment: @Hoppo What is unclear about it? You have to know how $u$ is dependent on $t$, e.g. you could have $u= t^3-\pi^t$

Comment: @Tavish am sorry ! Actually I have just started the basic so it might take few more pushes to make the concept clear .

Comment: @Hoppo That’s purely fine. Do you get it now?

Comment: @Tavish yes i did !

Answer (score 1):

Based on your equation, you are integrating kinetic energy

$$W_k = \frac{1}{2}mv^2 = \frac{1}{2}m \biggl(\frac{\partial x}{\partial t} \biggr)^2$$

with respect to time

$$I = \int W_kdt$$

If your velocity $v$ is constant with time, you will simply get

$$I = W_kt+C$$

where $C$ is some constant. However, if your velocity is not constant with respect to time, the result will be more complicated, and will depend on the exact form of $v$. Also take care that in some cases the mass $m$ may also depend on time, for example in rockets science where the burned fuel directly depletes the mass.

**Edit**: I suspect I know where your confusion comes from. If, for example, we were integrating momentum

$$p = mv = m\frac{\partial x}{\partial t}$$

with respect to time, we would be able to directly undo the differentiation in velocity and obtain an analytic expression for the result that is independent of the explicit form of the velocity

$$\int pdt = \int m\frac{\partial x}{\partial t} dt = mx+C$$

for some constant $C$. However, when we integrate energy, we first take a derivative of position to obtain velocity, then square it, then take anti-derivative (integral).

$$\frac{\partial x}{\partial t} \rightarrow \biggl(\frac{\partial x}{\partial t} \biggr)^2 \rightarrow \int \biggl(\frac{\partial x}{\partial t} \biggr)^2 dt$$

The problem is that the square does something very complicated to our function in such a way that we cannot directly reverse differentiation without knowing exactly what was the function. In other words, the square will affect different functions differently in this context. It is a common situation with nonlinearity